# How do carry save adders work?

Tags: adder, carry-look-ahead

I thought I understood the concept but [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carry-save_adder) has confused me. There are two outputs because one's for a partial sum and one's the carry bits. But why must it be used to "compute the sum of three or more n-bit numbers" why can't it compute 2 n-bit numbers?

Also the example given under the basic concept (where the result is `21122120202022022122111011102212`) confuses me more because that is just one output, not two?

Answer (score 2):

> But why must it be used to "compute the sum of three or more n-bit
>   numbers" why can't it compute 2 n-bit numbers?

The carry save addition of 2 N-bit numbers results in two (N + 1)-bit numbers being produced, the virtual carry (VC) and the virtual sum (VS).But after getting VC and VS you still have to add the two values together with a convectional adder to get your final result, so only adding 2 numbers is pointless.Take this example, lets say one carry-save addition takes k*T ms, where k = number of N - bit numbers being added, and a convectional adder takes 5T ms to add 2 numbers (regardless of bit width), then if:

1) you added 2 numbers, then

$$
\text{Time(Carry-Save) = 2T + 5T = 7T}
$$

$$
\text{Time(Convectional Adder) = 5T}
$$

2) you added 3 numbers, then

$$
\text{Time(Carry-Save) = 3T + 5T = 8T}
$$

$$
\text{*Time(Convectional Adder) = 5T + 5T = 10T}
$$

So carry-save addition is only useful if you have at least 3 operands to add.

> Also the example given under the basic concept (where the result is
>   21122120202022022122111011102212) confuses me more because that is
>   just one output, not two?

In reality there are two outputs, the representation that has been used there is a redundant arithmetic type representation.The number "21122120202022022122111011102212" will actually be represented as two different numbers, the virtual carry (VC) and the virtual sum (VS)

So A = 21122120202022022122111011102212 will be represented as

VC = 100110101010110110110000000011010

VS = 011001000000000000100111011100010

in your carry save adder.The VC number is obtained by looking at each and digit of A in turn, starting from the LSB, if the digit in a particular bit position, say bit position m, is 2 then place a 1 in the m th bit position of VC, otherwise place a zero.VS is obtained by setting all digits that are non-one in A to zero.You could also convert a redundant number to two non-redundant numbers by using the alternative method below.

Say you have B = 22012

Re-Write B using just binary by using 2 bits per digit, ie B =  10,10,00,01,10

Extract the first bit of each digit to form VC and the extract the last bit of each digit to form VS, ie( VC = 11001, VS =00010 )